# Search for specific return type in the Eclipse outline

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a huge Java class and I'd like to be able to see all the methods that return `MyOwnDataType`. I see that one can do CTRL+O and then type in something to print the methods whose name match the string that I just gave in.

I've discovered a partial solution: If I type *MyOwnDataType*, I get all methods that return `MyOwnDataType` and that have an argument of type `MyOwnDataType`.

Is there a way to do this (cleanly)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to type `*: MyOwnDataType`. Explanation:

- Searching the quick outline simply matches the exact outline node texts.
- Methods are formatted as `<name>(<arguments>) : <return type>`.
- You can use the `*` wildcard.

(Note that for me in Kepler, I have to type `*MyOwnDataType` (and not simply `MyOwnDataType`) to find methods with return or argument type `MyOwnDataType`.)

Comment: Great, thanks. Where can I read more about searching in the outline?

Comment: Search for "quick outline" in http://help.eclipse.org. :D Also, if you found the answer useful, feel free to accept it. :)

Comment: I don't seem to find that asterisk-colon syntax you used here in help.eclipse.org. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks for accepting! I added some explanation to the answer.